# How to change currently active version rust compiler?

Tags: rust, solana-cli

I experienced problems when building Solana CLI 1.18.7 with Rust

When I run `cargo build-sbf` an error appears:

```
error: package bumpalo v3.15.4 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.73.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.73.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p bumpalo@3.15.4 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of bumpalo supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev
```

It assumes currently active rustc version 1.72.0-dev, when I run `rustup -V`

```
rustup 1.27.0 (bbb9276d2 2024-03-08)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active rustc version is rustc 1.76.0 (07dca489a 2024-02-04)
```

This is the same when I run `rustc -V` currently active rustc version is 1.76.0.
When I downgrade Solana CLI, error package bumpalo detect rustc active version is 1.68.0.

How could this happen? Then how can I continue building Solana

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The repository probably has a `rust-toolchain.toml` file which pins a compiler version, thus why `rustup/rustc/cargo --version` reports different active toolchain versions in different directories.

If you have installed rust via rustup (which appears to be the case), you can specify a toolchain override on CLI like so: `cargo +<TOOLCHAIN> <COMMAND>`, in your case, try `cargo +stable build-sbf`. Alternatively, there is the `RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN` environment variable you can set, which might be more convenient if you are writing a CI script for example.

All this is well documented in rust's [official documentation](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html).

Comment: I tried running `cargo-build-sbf --version` result solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.7, platform-tools v1.39, rustc 1.72.0. I think this is the problem, can this rust version be changed?

Comment: Follow what's suggested in the answer please. Have you tried `cargo +stable build-sbf`?

Comment: And then try `RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN=stable cargo-build-sbf` if for some reason `cargo-build-sbf` cannot be run as a cargo subcommand.